# Timestamp not being entered correct when inserting into SQL

Tags: php, sql, date

I have a function which inserts data into a SQL database using the $wpdb->insert function. One of the data i would like is the time which the row was entered. However, using the current_time() returns 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Can anyone help please?

```
public function log_participant( $product_id, $current_user_id, $ticketnumber, $order_id ) {

        global $wpdb;
            $log_bid = $wpdb->insert(
                $wpdb->prefix . 'wc_lottery_log', array(
                    'userid'     => $current_user_id,
                    'lottery_id' => $product_id,
                    'ticketid'   => $ticketnumber,
                    'orderid'    => $order_id,
                    'date'       => current_time( 'mysql' ),
                ), array( '%d', '%d', '%d', '%s' )
            );

        return $wpdb->insert_id;
    }

foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
                    if ( function_exists( 'wc_get_order_item_meta' ) ){
                        $item_meta = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '' );
                    } else{
                        $item_meta = method_exists( $order, 'wc_get_order_item_meta' ) ? $order->wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id ) : $order->get_item_meta( $item_id );
                    }
                    $product_id   = $this->get_main_wpml_product_id( $item_meta['_product_id'][0] );
                    $product_data = wc_get_product( $product_id );

                    if ( $product_data && $product_data->get_type() == 'lottery' ) {
                        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_lottery', '1' );
                        add_post_meta( $product_id, '_order_id', $order_id );
                        delete_post_meta( $product_id, '_order_hold_on', $order_id );
                        $log_ids = array();

                        for ( $i = 0; $i < $item_meta['_qty'][0]; $i++ ) {
                            add_post_meta( $product_id, '_participant_id', $order->get_user_id() );
                            $participants = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_lottery_participants_count', true ) ? get_post_meta( $product_id, '_lottery_participants_count', true ) : 0;
                            update_post_meta( $product_id, '_lottery_participants_count', intval( $participants ) + 1 );
                            $this->add_lottery_to_user_metafield( $product_id, $order->get_user_id() );
                            $ticketnumber = $this->add_lottery_ticket_number($product_id);
                            $log_ids[] = $this->log_participant( $product_id, $order->get_user_id(), $ticketnumber, $order_id, $item );
                        }
                        do_action( 'wc_lottery_participate', $product_id, $order->get_user_id(), $order_id, $log_ids, $item, $item_id );
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (`0000-00-00 00:00:00` isn't a valid timestamp.)

Comment: Wordpress uses `current_time('mysql')` itself when saving posts or pages. so I guess that the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: But you are missing a `%d` in your array, right? you have 5 variables, but only 4 insertions?

Comment: so `array( '%d', '%d', %d,'%d', '%s' )`

Comment: You're right @Stender, thank you :)